# How to convert this sql query to django orm

Tags: sql, django

this is SQL query how to convert in Django ORM

```
SELECT app_product.id 
FROM app_product 
left JOIN app_order ON app_product.id = app_order.product_id 
GROUP BY app_product.id
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? Do you simply want `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: Why do you LEFT JOIN app_order when none of its columns are selected? Doesn't affect the query result at all.